# ggplot2: creating different graph panels per id

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a time series plot for each individual (ID) I have in my dataset.

Example data:

```
ID <- rep(c(2:5), each = 9, times = 4)
Attitude <- rep(c('A1', 'A2','A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9'), 16)
Answer <- rep(1:5, length.out = 144)
time <- as.character(rep(c(0, 1, 3, 4), each = 9, times = 4))
first_answer <- rep(1:5, length.out = 144)

df <- data.frame(ID, Attitude, Answer, time, first_answer)
df$time <- as.character(df$time)
```

The function code I am currently using:

```
library(dplyr) 
spaghetti_plot <- function(input, MV, item_level){
  MV <- enquo(MV)
  titles <- enquo(item_level)
  input %>% 
  filter(!!(MV) == item_level) %>% 
  mutate(first_answer = first_answer) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes( x = time, y = jitter(Answer), group = ID)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = first_answer)) +
  labs(title = titles ,x = 'Time', y = 'Answer', colour = 'Answer given at time 0')
}
```

This gives me a graph where I have a line for each individual, i.e. one plot for all individuals (equal to number of `ID`). Instead of this, I would like to have 1 plot with # panels = `ID`. For example, if I have data of 10 individuals, I would like to have a graph with 10 panels.

I tried using `facet_wrap` and `facet_panel` to get the job done, but I haven't found a proper solution yet.

**EDIT** using `facet_wrap(~ID)` gives [image]

The result that I am after would look something like this: [image]

Which was originally made in `SAS`.

**EDIT2** Solution is in the comments.

Comment: try adding `facet_wrap(~ID)`

Comment: I did that, although it gives met many panels it look's kind of weird. Would upload the image if I knew how :)

Comment: Loks like that your `y` is not correctly set.

Comment: You have more ID's that ggplot can fit in the plot window as panels, so it is showing only the strip ids at the top of each panel; the actual graph panels have been resized down to nothing.  You could try a) removing or reducing size of strip labels, b) enlarging your graph window, or c) subsetting your data to plot fewer IDs at once so there is room to show each panel.

Comment: @JanBoyer Thanks, you are correct. Is there a way to downsize the number it shows? (as in the 1st image of the question). I would like to get more panels in without making the graph unable to be interpreted.

Comment: `+ theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 4))`

Comment: Thanks, the gray area however remains equally large. So it doesn't really help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from your reproducible example are a bit weird because you have only one value per ID, but I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(df,aes(x = time, y = Answer)) +
      geom_line()+
      facet_grid(. ~ ID)
```

[image]

If you have too many facets the data may not show up, try to increase the size of the plot window or export the image directly with ggsave. If you find the right parameters for ggsave all the plots should be visible on the saved image.